# I wrote the delete method according to the Laravel documentation, but the data is not deleted

Tags: laravel, routes, controller, laravel-blade, laravel-9

Employees.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @method static find($id)
 */
class Employees extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'employees';
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

EmployeesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Employees;

class EmployeesController extends Controller
{
    public function employees_salaries()
    {
        return view('director.employees_salaries');
    }

    public function employees()
    {
        $employees = Employees::all();
        return view('director.employees', ['employees'=>$employees]);
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $employees = Employees::find($id);
        $employees->delete();
        return redirect('/director.employees')->with('status', 'Your Data is Deleted');
    }
}
```

employees.blade.php file

```
<from action="/delete/{{$employee->id}}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-delete btn-form me-3">
                                   Delete
                                </button>
                            </from>
```

route.php file

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/employees', array(EmployeesController::class, 'employees'))->name('employees');
    Route::delete('/delete/{id}', array(EmployeesController::class, 'destroy'))->name('delete');
```

I cleared the cache but have no idea what the problem is. it looks like I wrote the function correctly

p.s version Laravel 9
mySQL 8
phpMyAdmin

Comment: I tried already, but it didn't work.

Comment: Default route file for laravel is `routes/web.php`. You mentioned `route.php` in the question. Did you change the default route file path?

Comment: inside your form action best to use `action="{{ route('delete', ['id' => $employee->id]) }}"`... and are you sure you catch the correct employees based on given id ? you can test it by adding dump and die `dd($employee)` inside `destroy()`

Comment: also best to named your model as singular form `Employee` instead of Employees

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to SO, i think youre not using the variable you assigned the value into,from controller in your blade view. maybe try to make sure you have the right variable or maybe try to use var dump.

try to put this in your controller b4 parsing value to view, to check whether you get the data you wanted or not

```
dd('$employees');
```

make sure you use the variable you assigned in your controller to your view

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Employees;

class EmployeesController extends Controller
{
    public function employees_salaries()
    {
        return view('director.employees_salaries');
    }

    public function employees()
    {
        $employees = Employees::all();
        return view('director.employees', ['employees'=>$employees]); //<< here you name the variable 'employees'
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $employees = Employees::find($id);
        $employees->delete();
        return redirect('/director.employees')->with('status', 'Your Data is Deleted');
    }
}
```

change this variable in view

```
<from action="/delete/{{$employee->id}}" method="POST"> //<< this one you use '$employee' instead of '$employees'
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-delete btn-form me-3">
                                   Delete
                                </button>
                            </from>
```

there might also be other problem, but for now thats what i can point out.
since im also learning.

Comment: He (FreddyK) uses `$employee` probably because of `foreach($employees as $employee) {` looping inside `view(director.employees)`